# How to sort remixes under remix artist name in iTunes

Tags: itunes, music

Is there some way to sort remixed versions of songs in iTunes under the remix artist's name?

As an example, Adventure Club has made a lot of songs that are remixes. For now, all these songs appear under the original artist's name with "(Adventure Club remix)" after the song name. However, I would like for all the songs by Adventure Club (remix or not) to appear under the artist, Adventure Club.

**I do know of one way to make this work:**
I can put the remix artist as the "Album Artist". This way the original artist's name is preserved, but the remix will sort under the remix artist's name. **However**, (and maybe I'm just being way too picky here) there are some cases where either (1) *the song actually appears on an album by the original artist* or (2) *the song does not actually appear on an album at all*. In these cases, putting the remix artist as "Album Artist" is inaccurate.

Thus, is there any other way to sort remixed versions of songs in iTunes under the remix artist's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is currently no other way to make this work, other than the workaround solution posted in the question above.

To restate the solution:
***''*** *I can put the remix artist as the "Album Artist". This way the original artist's name is preserved, but the remix will sort under the remix artist's name. However, (and maybe I'm just being way too picky here) there are some cases where either (1) the song actually appears on an album by the original artist or (2) the song does not actually appear on an album at all. In these cases, putting the remix artist as "Album Artist" is inaccurate.* ***''***

It seems as though I will have to deal with the small inaccuracies that this solution causes. At least the sorting of songs by artist will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Smart Playlist (File->New->Smart Playlist...)?

You might set it up to Match Any, with a couple of rules: 1) Artist/contains/"Adventure Club" and 2) Album Artist/contains/"Adventure Club".  (Without the quotes.)

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but then I would have to make a Playlist for every artist that remixes songs. I'd really like to be able to browse songs by artist on my Mac or iPhone and be able to see all songs that the artist has made; remixes and originals.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but rudimentary) workaround that I use is to set the remix artist as the artist and set the original artist as the composer.
I also parenthetically note the original artist in the track title for easy visualization.

So Get Info window in iTunes looks like:

- song name: some track title (somebody 1)
- artist: somebody 2
- composer: somebody 1
- year...

Dunno if that works for anyone else, but it has served me well.

Comment: This is a good solution for anyone who doesn't use the composer field to record the actual song composer